# Celery non blocking client

Tags: python, celery

```
import proj.tasks
import time
import sys
import socket
import logging
import datetime

lat_to, ts = proj.tasks.timeme(time.time())          <---- blocking call
lat_from = time.time() - ts
print lat_to, lat_from
```

Celery task blocks so I cant take advantage of many workers.
Is it possible to make that a non blocking call?

NOTE: Ive looked at tornado-celery as an option for non blocking celery client but I am not sure if i like that approach as i need to launch tornado celery web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling a celery task the method executes synchronously.  THe power of a task queue is putting a task on the queue and letting the workers asynchronously do their work.

You can do this using the task.[`delay`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#calling-the-task) method.

I'm not quiet sure what delay does internally but it returns very quickly, and the work of your method is not actually being done when you call it, your task is just being put on the work queue.

Answer (score 0):

[tornado-celery](https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery) works fine on my side, but it by default waits for task's result before callback,

```
class GenAsyncHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        response = yield gen.Task(tasks.sleep.apply_async, args=[3])
        self.write(str(response.result))
        self.finish()
```

if you want to have task callback options as below, you can try [my fork](https://github.com/jimhorng/tornado-celery/tree/pr_wait_for_ack)

1. After task sent
2. After task sent and ack-ed
3. To fit original celery
   behavior that task.apply_async() to get the AsyncResult first, then
   AsyncResult.get() to get actual task result in tornado asynchronous
   fashion

Comment: why would someone use tornado-celery? are `delay()` or `apply_async()` in celery  synchronous? if they are async methods ( as name of method `apply_async()` suggests , that the call is async, which means `non-blocking`) whats the problem in using default `celery`

Comment: @anekix Since I am a tornado-celery contributor, I think I'm somehow qualified to answer this :)
It depends on which level of non-blocking user wants. celery does async in code execution level, which means one piece of code can send task as message to message broker for another piece of code to continue the execution in worker. tornado does async at system I/O level, which means there's only 1 thread running, when i/o r/w occurs, it will register in system's event loop and being callback when there's data/timedout.

Comment: @anekix  So in the use case that tornado-celery solves is that, when one piece of code sending task/message to broker, it will initialize network I/O from socket level, when something wrong within this level (e.g. TCP buffer full, longer roundtrip) in tornado(single thread) context, whole thread is blocked, which cause tornado web server being blocked, that's why we need to make celery's "send task" as tornado async style as well, which will prevent whole tornado web server being blocked.

Comment: Thankyou for your response .i was just wondering if suppose i am using `twisted` then what should i use? as for the similar reasons you mentioned about tornado-celery, i think twisted will also not work with default celery. am i right?